# Area bounded by a region

Tags: calculus

Find the equation of the vertical line that divides the area of the region $R$ bounded by
$$ y=\dfrac{1}{16x^2}, \hspace{0.5cm} y=x, \hspace{0.5cm}  \text{ and } \hspace{0.5cm} 
 y=\dfrac{x}{12}$$
in half.

So the region bounded by these function can be found here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+y%3D1%2F%2816x%5E2%29+%2C+y%3Dx+%2C+y%3Dx%2F12+

From the image we can see that the TOP curve changes.

- From $0$ to $\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{4}}$, TOP FUNCTION is $y=x$
- From $\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{4}}$ to $\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{3}{4}}$, TOP FUNCTION is $y=\dfrac{x}{12}$

So, we have the following description for the TOTAL AREA:
$$ \int_0^{\sqrt[3]{1/4}} \left(x-\dfrac{x}{12}\right) \,dx + \int_{\sqrt[3]{1/4}}^{\sqrt[3]{3/4}} \left(\dfrac{1}{16x^2}-\dfrac{x}{12}\right) \,dx$$

After integrating, we get that the TOTAL AREA = $0.194452$.

Now we want the vertical line (i.e. $x=(blank)$) that we get us 1/2 * TOTAL AREA = $0.0972262$.

Note that the first integral of the TOTAL AREA = $0.18189$. So, the half-way point will be some $k$ in interval $\left[0,\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{4}}\right]$. To find that $k$ we need to solve the following equation:
$$ \int_0^k \dfrac{11x}{12} \,dx = 0.0972262$$

After solving this, I get $k=0.460576$.

My issue is that the answer is $0.3810$. Why? Can anyone see where I messed up?

Comment: The intersection of $y = x$ and $y = \frac{1}{16x^2}$ is $x = \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{16}}$ and not $\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{4}}$

Comment: @MathLover I knew I did something silly. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: What do you mean by “vertical line that divides the region”?  Do you mean the vertical line that passes through the top corner of the region?